# type declaration for array of <key, value> in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

sorry, noob question...

i tried to find way to declare this valid type of 'counts' variable.

```
  const rawData = ['a','b','c','d','d','e','a','b','c','f','g','h','h','h','e','a'];

  const getCountData = (rawData: string[]) => {
    const counts: Map<string, number>[] = [];
    rawData.forEach((x: string) => {
      counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; 
    });
    
    return Object.values(counts);
  }
```

with pure javascript without type declaration, it has a result like this:

> [ a: 3, b: 2, c: 2, d: 2, e: 2, f: 1, g: 1, h: 3 ]

count[x] is complaining type mismatch in typescript

> Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

any reference i can check with?

Comment: `String` and `string` are different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript

```
Map<String, Number>[]
```

means *an array of Map<String, Number>*. From your code, you are getting a map, not an array of maps.

You should use an object (`{}`), not an array (`[]`).

Also, you can define an object with a string as key and a number as value with

```
const counts: { [key: string]: number } = {};
```

You whole code properly typed would be:

```js
const getCountData = (rawData: string[]): number[] => {
    const counts: { [key: string]: number } = {};
    rawData.forEach((x: string) => {
      counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; 
    });
    
    return Object.values(counts);
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get? [Check the typescript playground, it works correctly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygYRAVzFAIgQyjmAXhgAoAnHAd13wC4ZoyBLMOAbQF0BKesNAWwBGCMpyIA+GAG8AUDHkxQkWKAxQI9KTDYBrBAE96jFnA68BwsjAC+RadYDcchRWp4cAOgBmIMgFEcYAALEhIADyMoZlYuCWlnBUV0TAg2MI47ElUUtIyAHzyYAAZYgGoYAEYHGASbLidE2rIkNDIwGAB5QQArBGAoDwA3HAAbNAQILOT1eudrGWclaBhXGgJiNgByHE2AGk3BPc3gI4ATM6OEI539w-2T-a8juCOg1-f9q-2djicFpdgzQgaBGsGIiBQ0zW5Coay4QA)